# Read in 5 numbers from a user and compute the frequency of positive numbers entered

Tags: java

Having difficulty trying to write code for this problem above. Please find the code below. Have to read in 5 numbers and compute the frequency of positive numbers entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab02Ex2PartB {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a  positive integer");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        for(int i = -2 ; i < 4 ; i++) 
            System.out.println("Positive Count is: " + i); 
    }           
}
```

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a task that needs to be repeated (about the user entering a value); but your **loop** (the perfect mean to do things repeatedly) ... doesn't *cover* that part!

for(int i=-2 ; i<4 ; i++) 
     System.out.println("Positive Count is: " +i);

Instead, do something like:

```
for (int loops = 0; loops < 5; loops++) {
  int number = input.nextInt();
```

Then of course, you need to **remember** those 5 values, the easiest way there: use an array; Turning your code into:

```
int loopCount = 5;
int numbers[] = new[loopCount]; 
for (int loops = 0; loops < loopCount; loops++) {
  numbers[loops] = input.nextInt();
```

And then, finally, when you asked for all numbers, then you check the data you got in your array to compute frequencies. A simple approach would work like this:

```
for (int number : numbers) {
  if (number > 0) {
    System.out.println("Frequency for " + number + " is: " + computeFrequency(number, numbers));
  }
```

with a little helper method:

```
private int computeFrequency(int number, int allNumbers[]) {
  ...
```

Please note: this is meant to get you going - I don't intend to do all your homework for you. You should still sit down yourself and figure what "computing the frequency" actually means; and how to do that.

Comment: The way I understood the question, he wants the frequencies of the positive numbers

Comment: Personally, I thing that `Collections`'s methods are more efficient. But I might be wrong

Comment: Sure. But those mean **additional** complexity. A newbie should start working with basics.

Comment: true, but this can also function as a jump start (as it did with me, when I was a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, Remember if you only want to know the frequency(not storing)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab02Ex2PartB {

    public static void main (String [] args){

    int i = 1;// is a counter for the loop
    int positive =0;// counts positive numbers
            while(i<=5){
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter a whole positive number");
                int number = input.nextInt();
                if(number > 0){
                    positive ++;
                }
                i++;
            }
    System.out.println("Positive Count is: "+ positive);
```